# Planck blackbody radiation

Tags: thermal-radiation, quantum-chemistry

I am reading a chapter about blackbody radiation in my physics textbook, and I encountered the following equation:
$$d\rho(\nu, T)=\rho_\nu(T)d\nu=\frac{8\pi k_BT}{c^3}\nu^2d\nu$$
which is a classical description of blackbody radiation.

I don't understand why
$$d\rho(\nu, T)=\rho_\nu(T)d\nu \, .$$
If you integrate both sides, you get a different equation, namely
$$\ln \rho = \nu + C$$
which contradicts the second part of the equation. Can anyone help anyone understand this equation?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot integrate that way, $\rho_\nu$ is the derivative,  $\rho_\nu=\frac{d\rho}{d\nu}$. The equations are the same because you just multiplied the left side on top and bottom by  $d\nu$